# How do I approach Ramanujan's nested root problem from a programmer standpoint?

Tags: python, python-3.x, math

I need to create a function in python that accepts a positive integer **n** and returns the value of a(n). The series goes as following:

> a1 = sqrt(1 + 2)
>
> a2 = sqrt(1 + 2 * sqrt(1 +3))
>
> a3 = sqrt(1 + 2 * sqrt(1 + 3 * sqrt(1 + 4)))
>
> a4 = sqrt(1 + 2 * sqrt(1 + 3 * sqrt(1 + 4 * sqrt(1 + 5))))
>
> etc...

Truth is, I dont even know where to begin. Any help would be greatly appriciated! Thanks in advance!

Comment: Determine a closed form of the equation ([see here](https://en.wikipedia.org/w/index.php?title=Nested_radical&section=7#Ramanujan's_infinite_radicals)) and then solve for it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is a possible solution:

```
from math import sqrt

def a(n):
    result = 1
    for i in reversed(range(1, n + 1)):
        result = sqrt(1 + (i + 1) * result)
    return result
```

Comment: Thank you very much! I'm gonna give it a try! And yes! That's the solution! Much appriciated man!!

Comment: I can't upvote yet! I need to "level up" first! or else i would've! Oh never mind I dont know how the site works yet. I think i upvoted your awnser now!